# jQuery-ui autocomplete click on the list works only first time, second time it is remains unselectable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am working on jquery ui autocomplete in the fixed position div, used appendTo option it works on the first time populates all the data and in second time it populates the data, but remains unselectable. Click on the list do nothing.

But by removing appendTo from jquery autocomplete. it works like charm. but the ui list is mispositioned on scroll. Kindly help me out in this problem

Comment: Can you please provide your code? Our psychic powers are not what they *will* be :)

Comment: Link for the above problem.. [http://jsfiddle.net/do3e7n40/](http://jsfiddle.net/do3e7n40/).... Kindly help me out

Comment: keyboard navigation throught list will work.. but mouse click will not work in any of the browser

Comment: I see what you mean now... Looks like the slide out is damaging the styling for the popup autocomplete list.

Comment: Yeah, i am totally spending it on 3 hours to work on it. Still didn't sort out whats the problem

Comment: I see now that the `tabSlideOut` you are using has no events. This answer will let you hack it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974780/jquery-tabslideout-plugin-and-want-to-detect-when-div-slide-in-and-out but I suggest you find another slideout plugin that does not interfere with autocomplete.

Comment: thanks for your immediate response. will try method on that discussion